# Generating graphs from distributed test seems to give results for one client/slave

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm running a distributed test using 5 JMeter clients (slaves). Each client is set to run 50 users. At the conclusion of the test I generate a series of graphs from the resulting JTL along with a SynthesisReport. The SynthesisReport details 250 samples for each request, as you'd expect, however the TimeVsThreads and the ThreadsStateOverTime peak at 50 users, as if they were showing the results from just one of the clients.

I've confirmed that the jmeter.properties files for each client are the same as I suspected that it was possibly an issue with the each clients results file configuration and settings for saveservice.

I can't imagine this is by design, has anyone experienced something similar and if so how did was it solved?

Comment: Hi, any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/

Just name your thread groups using a unique id for each generator ( [hostname](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or a property you pass to injector and use with function [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) if you have more than 1 injector per host) and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for Jmeter Distributed Testing.

The reason this occurs is that each load generator separately starts User Threads 1-50, so when cmdrunner runs, it sees 1 responses from each User Thread 1 (5 total), but can't differentiate between them.

If you're using a custom reporter tool (that wraps cmdrunner), you can multiply your peak users by your load generators to display a more accurate number at the top of your Report. But as long as you're calling cmdrunner, you won't be able to see the actual number of users on your graphs.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior of JMeter. 5 clients will run each 50 threads.
Open JMeter and run on all remote hosts, and check Active threads each will run 50 threads.